# HystrixCommand annotation is not working on type variables

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix, turbine

I am using type variables in my abstract parent service class where I have some service methods. I am using @HystrixCommand annotation to use some fallback method.

Here is my sample code

```
@Service
public abstract class MyAbstractParentClass<T extends IModel<T>,S extends Serializable> implements IService<T, S>, InitializingBean{


private MyRepo<T, S > repo;

@Override
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod="handleError", groupKey="MyClass", commandKey="findUserTest")
public T findUserTest(S userId){
    String str = null;
    System.out.println(str.length());// intentional nullpointer exception
    T user  = repo.findOne(userId);
    return user;
}

public T handleError(S userId){
    T user  = repo.findOne(userId);
    return user;
}

public abstract MyRepo<T, S> getRepository();

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    repo = getRepository();

}
}
```

But unfortunately after using the annotation my api is not working it is giving the below java heap space error.

`{
    "timestamp": 1500581418921,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError",
    "message": "Java heap space",
    "path": "/rest/api/path"
}`

If I do not use any type variables it is working fine in the parent class

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod="handleError", groupKey="MyClass", commandKey="findUserTest")
public String findUserTest(String userId){
    String str = null;
    System.out.println(str.length());

    return userId;
}

public String handleError(String userId){

    return "Error Handled";
}
```

If I use this annotation in any of my child classes service methods, fallback mechanism is working fine.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Does it have to do with the type or the fact it's defined in an abstract class?

Comment: @spencergibb It is not due to the abstract class. Because I checked in the abstract class by removing all Type variables. Fallback is working fine. I have added bit more details.